# Values of Environment variables from AWS Paramter store is prefixed by $ which is not intended

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile

I have a list of env variables defined under parameter store in AWS(Systems Manager) and am using the below dockerfile and am using https://github.com/Droplr/aws-env this for handling environment variables.

```
FROM node:6-wheezy
COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN npm install pm2 -g
RUN npm install
RUN wget https://github.com/Droplr/aws-env/raw/master/bin/aws-env-linux-amd64 -O /bin/aws-env && \ chmod +x /bin/aws-env
VOLUME ["/var/logs"]
EXPOSE 8080
CMD eval $(aws-env) && pm2 start app.js -i 1 --name servicename --no-daemon
```

For some reasons, all the values of environment variables are prefixed by $ sign when its used inside the application using (process.env)

Where I have gone wrong? anything in dockerfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many Docker images (e.g. ruby) are using /bin/sh as a default shell. It crashes $'string' notation that enables multi-line variables export. For this reason, to use aws-env, it's required to switch shell to /bin/bash:

```
     CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "eval $(aws-env) && rails s Puma"]
```